# woocommerce_product_thumbnails hook now depreciated? What would be a work around?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to add a video underneath the gallery of a single product page (woocommerce). When I add the hook "woocommerce_product_thumbnails" nothing happens. I noticed that on the visual guide to woocommerce hooks it says "woocommerce_product_thumbnails (may not work with the new product gallery since WC 3.0)". Is there a work around to get this to work again?

Here is my current code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'add_product_video');

function add_product_video(){

    echo "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/JHN7viKRxbQ' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241524/how-to-make-woocommerce-3-0-single-image-gallery-so-it-is-like-version-2-x/43241525#43241525

Comment: That hook still exists in [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/103f674d185c6aff3ed18c9762825675f61d3151/templates/single-product/product-image.php#L60) if you are using the `product-image.php` template anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `do_action()` function to make it possible in other way. In your woocommerce folder navigate to this path: `woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php`

On the line no.22, add:

```
do_action("woocommerce_add_my_video");
```

And inside your theme functions.php, put:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_my_video', 'add_product_video');
function add_product_video(){

    echo "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/JHN7viKRxbQ' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

}
```

See the reference link here : [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: **Good alternative! +1** … Is not recommended to edit the plugin files. Instead you should include this in your answer with a bit more details: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), adding also this link as reference.

Comment: To extend what LoicTheAztec said this answer is only a temporary fix because as soon as WooCommerce updates the change you make to tabs.php would be undone, therefor it's recommended to override WooCommerce templates by copying them into your theme or child theme. On a side note there are plenty of hooks available so there should be no need to create your own, why not use something like `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` as seen [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-single-product.php).

Comment: [Overriding Woocommerce templates via the theme,](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) Is one of the main features in WooCommerce plugin to make customizations, as they change rarely and are not crushed by the plugin updates. For sure using available hooks is a better way when possible, but sometimes they can become deprecated too…

Comment: To go off of Kodaloid, I had tried that before and it kept going on top of the gallery. What I was missing wast the priority level. I added a high priority number at the end of the function and it moved it below.

Another (not perfect option) was putting it after the single product summary, floating to the left, and adding a negative margin. This route you just need to add some code in your media queries for responsiveness. Thank for your help everyone!